# ' undefined reference to' error when trying to overload operator =

Tags: c++

I bumped in to an error when trying to overload operator =

Not sure what is wrong with the code. Thanks for help!

Here is my code:

**matrix.h**

```
namespace MATRIX{
  class Matrix{
      // other private methods
      public:
          // other public methods
          template < typename T >
          Matrix& operator=(std::list<T> & data) ;
  }
};
```

**matrix.cu**

```
namespace MATRIX{
   // other definitions
   template < typename T >
   Matrix& Matrix::operator=(list<T> & data) {
       // method definition
   }
}
```

**test.cu**

```
#include <list>
#include "matrix.h"
// other includes
int main(void){
    using namespace std;
    using MATRIX::Matrix;
    Matrix k_matrix;
    list<double> k_list(100);
    // initialize k_list
    k_matrix = k_list;
}
```

**Build**

```
nvcc -c matrix.cu
nvcc -o test test.cu matrix.o
```

**Error on second command**

```
 tmpxft_00001f0f_00000000-3_test.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x202): 
 undefined reference to`MATRIX::Matrix& MATRIX::Matrix::operator=<double> 
 (std::list<double, std::allocator<double> >&)'
```

Comment: I just added that. LOL. This compile command is ok with other methods.

Comment: Templates cannot be split into definition and implementation

Comment: This has nothing to do with CUDA, by the way.  This is all host code, and `nvcc` simply hands host code off to the host compiler.

Comment: Thanks Angew! The method should be defined in header file! @Robert Crovella, I removed cuda and thrust tag.

Comment: Why is list parameter not const reference?